# is co.cc free for ever?

Tags: domains, name

hello
any one can tell me that is co.cc domain free for life?
when i go to register a co.cc domain name it shows only 2 years for free, so is it free for ever or i have to pay after passing 2 year

Comment: Wrong site to ask the question.

Answer (score 3):

For a personal site, Co.cc is free forever, you just have to renew the domain every so often (I think those two years).

If it's a business website, you do have to pay, but I think it's only $5 a year, but if you're willing to pay money, bump it up to $10 and get a real domain.

Comment: +1 for a real domain. A nice .com domain isn't that expensive and you don't have to worry.